# PHP $_SESSION lost over several pages

Tags: php, session-variables

I am setting `session_start()` on every page as very 1st statement.

The 1st page sets `$_POST['myVar']` when the page ist submitted. The 2nd page evaluates this by a php lib which sets `$_SESSION['myVar']` if this is set in $_POST and not set already in `$_SESSION`.

When submitting this form and calling the 3rd one evaluating there `$_SESSION['myVar']` results that the variable is no more set! There is no `session_unset()` called between.

Theoretically all is correct but the use shows the opposite. What may there be wrong or still missing?

Comment: Try to output all session variable for each request.

Comment: Do you mind share your code? We cannot understand whether your problem is due to wrong use of variable or some unexpected problems.

Comment: *"page sets `$_POST['myVar']`"* – *<screeching halt, full stop>* It does what now how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In the page you have a form, probably your first page session is not required.  In the next page(form action page), you need to start the session first.  Then you can give like $_SESSION['fieldName']=$_POST['fieldName'].  After this in whichever pages you use session_start(), you can have the data.  Hope this helps..